# want to open a page in my current page with href when I click on a menu element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a menu made with ul and li elements I use href to open a page when I click on one of the li , the problem is that I want to open the page that contains href in the same page in the main file, because I have a footer and a header.

Comment: After reading the question, I feel like I turned two pages at once. Can you explain in a little more detail what the problem is?

Comment: i'm making a page that have a menu : home, profile,etc what I want is when I click for example on profile , I load the page containing the informations on the same window . without losing my menu

Comment: Why would it open in any other page unless you specifically told it to at some point?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now, along with the template?

Comment: i want something like stackoverflow when you press tags users or badges etc , the result is shown on the same place not in a new window that's what I want .

Comment: Then create a menu and include it in your pages.

Comment: Why don't you use an iframe?

Comment: ***unclear what you're asking***  
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it and **without page refresh** is to use
 **AJAX** technology and **JS** (+ just a bit of **jQuery**)

### Search Engine friendly AJAX driven website:

**BASIC EXAMPLE:**

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>AJAX driven site - by Roko C.B. - TEST</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php include 'menu.html'; ?>
```

**menu.html**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="index.php"> HOME </a></li> 
    <li><a href="foo.php"> FOO </a></li>
    <li><a href="bar.php"> BAR </a></li>  
</ul>
```

**footer.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){ // DOM Ready (shorthand)

    window.onpopstate = function(e) {
        if(e.state){
            $("#content").html( e.state.html );
            document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
        }
    };

  $('#nav a').click(function(e) {
  
      e.preventDefault();                // prevent default anchor behavior
      var URL = $(this).attr('href');    // get page URL
      $('#page').html('');               // empty old HTML content.
      // Target URL and get the #content element
      // and put it into #page of this page
      $('#page').load(URL +' #content', function(data){
           // Load callback function.
           // Everything here will be performed once the load is done.
           // Put here whatever you need.
           // ...
           
           // Also, let's handle history and  browser's AddressBar
            var $data     = $(data),
                content   = $data.find('#content').html(),
                pageTitle = $data.find('h1').text();
            window.history.pushState({"html":content, "pageTitle": pageTitle},"", URL );
      });
      
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Than all you need are your pages with the content:

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?> <!-- header has menu.html -->
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
         <h1>WELCOME!</h1>
         <p>Article here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**foo.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?> <!-- header has menu.html -->
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
         <h1>FOO!</h1>
         <p>Foo Article here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?> <!-- header has menu.html -->
<div id="page">
    <div id="content">
         <h1>BAR!</h1>
         <p>Bar Article here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

<sub>**Documentation**:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

http://api.jquery.com

http://api.jquery.com/load/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onpopstate

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do from reading you post is have the header and footer in their own separate files.

On all the pages include this header and footer where you want them, so when you open the new page up the header and footer will be the same across all the pages.

same for the menu. put it in its own file and include it in every page. then its always the same across every page and you only have to update one file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for, I've written a html page for you to demonstrate how you can use `anchor tag` to set your **hyperlink reference(`href`)** to the same page.

Try this

```
<html>
  <body>
  <a href="#footer">Go to footer</a>
    <div><a id="header">Your Header</a></div>
    <div style="height:900px;"></div>
    <div><a id="footer">Your Footer</a></div>
    <a href="#header">Go to Header</a>
</body>
</html>
```

## Update

Finally I got your problem, you want to use same footer and header on all your pages...Right??

Actually you are looking for a code that lets you use your already designed `PHP` files.
So you need just to use php `include()` function

**Syntax:**

Before your header section

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

Before your footer section

```
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

### Note:

You can also use `<?php require 'header.php'; ?>`

but this can generate an error in case your header and footer files are missing.

Comment: this is not what I want

Comment: @LazyBrain Oh...I am sorry, but what you really want then

Comment: i want something like stackoverflow when you press tags users or badges etc , the result is shown on the same place not in a new window that's what I want

Comment: Ohkk.... Are you using Visual studio for ASP.NET website

Comment: no im working with php .

Comment: PHP...?? In this case I'll recommend you to use some javascript on your variable page section, since you're not posting your html code, nobody can help you anymore... but I can suggest you .... use div tags and then after you can use javascript to hide or show another divs

Comment: @LazyBrain ... I've written a code for you again, this times it seems to work, tell me if this works for you

Comment: I think so...but are there other optimal solutions ?

Comment: i'm just asking because i'm a beginner !!!

Comment: In my opinion, there are no other solutions in `PHP` which you can use  for this purpose, please elaborate your problem - I don't think that anything could be better than these 2 lines of code to include your header and footer php files

Answer (score 0):

@LazyBrain : then u just have to play around with id's.
for example:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#questions">Questions</a></li>
<li><a href="#tags">Tags</a></li>
<li><a href="#answer">Answers</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="questions">
....................
put your content for question page here


</div>
```

Comment: The OP is not asking for anchor tags, OP just wants to use old header and footer php files, you can see my answer's previous edit and the last answer who is also referring for w3 schools

Comment: @Đēēpak Shãrmã : Sir he wants the links should be opened in same page so it will b only done by anchor tag i think.

Comment: Yes, Agreed this is not our problem. The question is very unclear. I also suggested same to him, but as you can read my previous edits...He is not asking for this..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the target attribute within the href, take it out and you will open the link in the same window.

e.g.

```
<a href="page.html" target="_blank">Click Here</a> - New window
```

Should be

```
<a href="page.html">Click Here</a> - Current window
```